# Why on Private Group Member can view a button named "Invite People", while they can not share the Group not the site

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, microsoft-teams

We have created a Private Office 365 Group, where in this case members of the group can not share the group with others + we are not allow users to share the sharepoint site with other.

here is the private setting:-

[image]

here is the setting to prevent users from sharing the sharepoint site:-

[image]

but even we define the above settings, still Group's Members can view the "Invite People" button, as follow:-

[image]

and most surprising that they can view the button and invite others to join the group and/or the site, but no invitation will be sent.. so is there a bug inside sharepoint where this button "Invite People" should not be shown to member users?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, this is the correct behaviour. Users with the appropriate access can still invite users to join their private group or access a SharePoint site. A public group means anyone can join the group by adding themselves, while a private group means a user with the correct access will need to add them to the group.

**Edit:** Further clarification can be found in Microsoft's documentation

> Members can access everything in the group, but can't change
> group settings. By default group members can invite guests to join
> your group, though you can control that setting.

[Overview of Microsoft 365 Groups for administrators](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/create-groups/office-365-groups?view=o365-worldwide)

Comment: ok in my case the "Invite People" is been shown for members inside private groups,,, while it should not,,., and the button is been shown but you can not actually add users... so seems there is a bug

Comment: and in private groups only the group owner can invite other.. but members can not

Comment: I have updated the answer. As stated by Microsoft's documentation, members can invite users to join the group by default.

Comment: this is for public groups while for private groups only the group owners can invite others

Comment: Nowhere in the documentation does it state that this is for public groups. Anyone can join a public group and does not require anyone to invite them. In private groups, members can invite users to join the group as stated in the documentation.

Comment: this is wrong check those 2 docs https://sharepointmaven.com/public-vs-private-office-365-groups/ + https://www.avepoint.com/blog/office-365/microsoft-office-365-groups-public-vs-private-groups/ ... in short check this pic @ https://www.avepoint.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/table-1-2.png

Comment: Those links are for third party sites, the link in the answer is from Microsoft themselves. Microsoft's documentation takes precedent over any third party since it is them who develop SharePoint.

Comment: what you are saying that members can share a private group with other users is totally wrong

Comment: It is not me who is saying this, it is Microsoft. If you genuinely believe there is a bug, you can report it to Microsoft via the admin center. It's likely they will respond with the exact same documentation I have linked.

Comment: ok did you try to create a private group >> add a test user as member >> try to share the group with a second test user using the first test user.. this is simply will not work!

Comment: You should report it as a bug via the admin center if the behaviour differs from the documentation that has been linked.